# `function go()` vs `go = function()`

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, internet-explorer-8

I ran into what seems to be a silly issue with some Javascript:

```
go = function () {
    alert("Go!");
}

$(function () {
    go();
});
```

When the page loads I get an error:

> Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;
>   MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;
>   Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR
>   2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0;
>   .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NAP 1.1)
>   Timestamp: Thu, 17 Mar 2011 20:18:03
>   UTC
>
> *Message: Object doesn't support this
>   property or method Line: 1 Char: 1
>   Code: 0 URI:
>   http://localhost:61710/Scripts/number.js*

When I change the `go` initializer to this:

```
function go() {
    alert("Go!");
}
```

...everything works just fine.

What am I missing? Also, is there a reason to use one form of function initializer over the other?

**Edit:**
I get this error when I run the code in an instance of IE8 using the built-in Visual Studio web server (*Start without Debugging*). When I run the code in a separate instance of IE8 without Visual Studio, it works just fine. Perhaps Visual Studio forces IE to use stricter JS compiler settings?

Comment: can you post what browser you are using?

Comment: Your original works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Xz3s5/ on IE8, FF3.3.6, Chrome 10.0.648.151, and Opera 10.63.

Comment: I'm using IE8. See the user agent section of the error details.

Comment: Looks like I only get the error when the IE8 instance is attached to Visual Studio.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should declare the variable first:

```
var go = function () {
    alert("Go!");
}
```

One reason to use this form is that it can help and avoid polluting the global namespace with your functions (see an example of this notion [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/luisabreu/archive/2009/08/28/avoiding-global-namespace-pollution-using-namespaces.aspx)).

Comment: s/need/should/ is more technically correct.  It should (and does) work without using var to scope it.  Of course, if you use var in the outermost scope, it doesn't really make much difference.

Answer (score 3):

The difference (and may help you decide which is better over another) is that

```
go = function () {
    alert("Go!");
}
```

is defined at parse-time whereas

```
function go() {
    alert("Go!");
}
```

is defined at run-time.

P.S., it works for me, however you may need to do:

```
var go = ...
```

rather than

```
go = ...
```

Comment: +1 for the parse-time vs run-time thing. That answered an ongoing issue I've had with the order in which I initialize and call my functions.

Answer (score 1):

work fine for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/vEKgX/

although try this instead:

```
var go = function () {
    alert("Go!");
}

$(go);
```